# Can you add the probabilities of a classifier to better predict an outcome?

Tags: r, scikit-learn, data-mining, prediction, random-forest

Say I am interested in predicting the TOTAL number of people that survive the titanic disaster, NOT each individual who died. Is it possible to run a probabilistic classifier on the data getting a value for each individual between 0 and 1, then summing those values for a best guess?